# Display amount of registered users in MySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, statistics

I want to display the current amount of users registered in my database (it's called dalton) / the users are stored in a table in that database called simpleauth_players. It stores their name, hash, registerdate, logindate, and lastip.

I want to somehow use a PHP code that (logs me into the database) and displays the current amount of names in the database. So I can display a message like "Hey, there is currently 1,894 registered players!" inside of my HTML/PHP page. I'm kinda a novice it would be awesome if somebody could share the code and instructions.

My code:

```
$connection = mysql_connect('host', 'username', 'password');
mysql_select_db('database');

$query = "SELECT * FROM simpleauth_players"; 
$result = mysql_query($query);
$registered = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dalton.tables WHERE simpleauth_players = 'name' and     TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE';

echo "$registered"; 

mysql_close();
```

Comment: You can count the DB rows with a query like `select count(*) from simpleauth_players`.  I don't know PHP so I can't help with emitting this number in the pages being generated, but that may get you started.

Comment: do you want to display only PHP users or do you want to display a count by each user type ?

Comment: @DaltonEdwards Why, didn't my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/27586695/ not do what you wanted to achieve? It counts the number of rows in a given table. My answer used `mysqli_` since you did not provide any information on which API you used to connect with. It can easily be changed to `mysql_`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code I used to display the amount of registered players (AKA rows) in the simpleauth_players table.

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
mysql_select_db("dalton", $link);
if ($_GET['task'] == 'total') {
    $get_db = 'simpleauth_players';
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $get_db", $link);
        echo '{"task":"total","amount":"';
            echo mysql_num_rows($result);
        echo '"}';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one assumed that your column name is `language`

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM simpleauth_players WHERE language = "PHP"
```

or if you want to get count by each language type you can use this

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS Count,language FROM simpleauth_players GROUP BY language
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your [**original post/question**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27586598/1) Since you have not provided us with the MySQL API you're using to connect with, here's an `mysqli_` version, using MySQL's aggregate [`COUNT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html) function, which will count the number of given rows in a table:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect('host', 'username', 'password', 'database');
$result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT  COUNT(*) as count
            FROM simpleauth_players"

);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $var = $row['count'];

    echo "There are currently " .$var. " users.";

}
```

---

**Edit:** if using `mysql_`

```
$connection = mysql_connect('host', 'username', 'password');
if (!$connection) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db('database', $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use database : ' . mysql_error());
}

$result = mysql_query("SELECT  COUNT(*) as count
            FROM simpleauth_players", $connection);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $var = $row['count'];

    echo "There are currently " .$var. " users.";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) as total_player from simpleauth_players
```

OR

```
$sql = "select * from simpleauth_players";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$count = mysqli_num_rows();

echo "Total ".$count." Players";
```

Comment: Don't I have to add the MySQL login credentials somewhere in that code?